# Convert SQL.Bak to BacPac

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I'm using SQL server 2012, I have a Database file (.bak) trying to export it to a (.BacPac) file so I can import it to Azure. The problem is in the converting progress (Validating scheme model),

I have the following error :

1. > "Error SQL71501: View: [dbo].[AC_Section] has an unresolved reference to object [dbo].[sueres].".
2. > "Error SQL71562: Procedure: [dbo].[milp] has an unresolved reference to object [tempdb].[dbo].[sysob].[xtyp]."

and the errors are going with many other tables and objects.

How do I solve this or if there is another way to convert the database to .bacpac.

Comment: Unfortunately,Azure database migration assistant won't analyze procedures and show the issues like the one you got..

You need to manually fix those errors which will show only while importing bacpac

Answer (score 1):

Try to resolve invalid objects before migrating the database to SQL Azure. Invalid objects are objects (stored procedures, views, etc.) that are making reference to objects no longer exist, including objects on tempdb.

```
SELECT 
    QuoteName(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(referencing_id)) + '.' 
        + QuoteName(OBJECT_NAME(referencing_id)) AS ProblemObject,
    o.type_desc,
    ISNULL(QuoteName(referenced_server_name) + '.', '')
    + ISNULL(QuoteName(referenced_database_name) + '.', '')
    + ISNULL(QuoteName(referenced_schema_name) + '.', '')
    + QuoteName(referenced_entity_name) AS MissingReferencedObject
FROM
    sys.sql_expression_dependencies sed
        LEFT JOIN sys.objects o
            ON sed.referencing_id=o.object_id
WHERE
    (is_ambiguous = 0)
    AND (OBJECT_ID(ISNULL(QuoteName(referenced_server_name) + '.', '')
    + ISNULL(QuoteName(referenced_database_name) + '.', '')
    + ISNULL(QuoteName(referenced_schema_name) + '.', '')
    + QuoteName(referenced_entity_name)) IS NULL)
ORDER BY
    ProblemObject,
    MissingReferencedObject
```

I would like to recommend you using Data Migration Assistant before migrating the database to SQL Azure. This tool does not detect invalid objects at this time.

[Microsoft Data Migration Assistant v3.1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53595)

Hope this helps.

Regards,

Alberto Morillo

Comment: I tried the tool but turns out that our server "have insufficient server-level permissions to perform migration. The credentials used to connect to the target server must be a member of the system admin server role."

Answer (score 0):

So I came to a conclusion that some data, functions, tables, objects and etc... in my **(.bak)** file are **not supported** by Azure, or you can say they're outdated. The ways to deploy the (.bak) file to Azure is by avoiding, deleting or re-write these data before deploying the file to Azure, which is going to change the data flow.